# sorting data from API GET

Tags: reactjs, api, sorting

I'm currently trying to sort a set of data from A-Z from an API call (an array of objects), right now I have the code set up:

```js
class WarehouseDetails extends React.Component {
    state = {          
        WarehouseDetails: [
            
        ],
        WarehouseInventory: [
            
        ]
    }

     sortItems = () => {
         axios.get('/inventory')
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    WarehouseInventory: res.data.itemName.sort()
                    })
                })
    }
```

I'm passing the function `sortItems` through props to my component where it's then being handled as an `onClick` attribute in an anchor tag. Any thoughts why this isn't working?

Comment: use `componentDidMount` lifecycle method or `useEffect` hook to perform a fetching.

Comment: If I already have a componentDidMount setting my default state, should I use a componentDidUpdate?

Comment: isnt mandatory to use `componentDidUpdate`